# directive uses value comes from ngRepeat in the same element tag

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

a simple custom directive uses the value coming from ngRepeat, this directive is located on the same element that has the ngRepeat.

Please see plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/HHDT8q4srsr5ZRYJAhDR?p=preview

the directive works fine, the {{item.locked}} has value you can see them when displaying outside the

tag. But the directive doesn't seem to be able to determine what is the value in {{item.locked}}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `attrs.ciProductLocked` it just grabs the string in the html. You want to evaluate a variable so you can do something like this:

```
// in the directive
if(scope.$eval(attrs.ciProductLocked)){
  el.addClass('ui-state-disabled');
}
// in the dom
ci-product-locked="item.locked"
```

This evaluates the string item.locked in the context of the scope, and will get you the actual value.
Here is the updated code http://plnkr.co/edit/rEslCHqfdy8H82e0o4KJ?p=preview.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks! the $eval was what I missed!

Comment: cool, please mark as answer so that others can see what helped you out.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things going on with your example that make it a little confusing.

First of all, if you're only looking for a way to add a CSS class to an item based on a boolean, you should use ng-class:

```
<li ng-class="{ ui-state-disabled: item.locked }" ...>
```

Secondly, if you're trying to have the value of a scope variable passed into a directive, it's a bit easier to use a new scope and bind the attributes - [the angular directive guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) has comprehensive info here.

Third, when binding a scope value to an attribute, you'll probably want to use the value uninterpreted:

```
<li ci-product-locked="item.locked" ...>
```

This will be bound dynamically if you've declared the ci-product-locked attribute as being passed through to your directive in your linking function.